# Как сравнить строки в многомерном массиве?

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужно сравнить строки в многомерном массивы и вывести количество одинаковых.
Код работает не так надо.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int m = 4;
    int col=1;
    int a[m][m] = {{1,1,1},{1,32,1},{1,3,1},{1,2,1}};
           bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
         flag = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (a[i][j]==a[i+1][j]) {
                flag = true;
            } 
            else {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
    }

if (flag) {
            col++;
        }
}
cout << col;
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Чтобы написать решение - как нужно реагировать на строки 1,1,1; 1,2,1; 1,1,1; 1,2,1; 1,3,1; 1,1,1? Какой ответ верный? 3? 2? 5?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vstr;
    std::set<std::string> sstr;
    vstr.push_back("1");
    vstr.push_back("2");
    vstr.push_back("1");
    vstr.push_back("3");
    for (auto &elem: vstr) {
        sstr.insert(elem);
    }
    std::cout << "Equal = " << (vstr.size() - sstr.size()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто в задании мне нужен именно массив

Comment: Масив чего? Масив вместо вектора, масив вместо строки, масив вместо %s? И добавьте тогда метку `C` потому что в `C++`  вообще говоря не принято юзать сишние масивы.